# Update commandline printf information from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, printing

My situation is, I have some datas that will be printed from two different threads.

However, because this data is only an increasing of number, I want to print it in one line
using '\r'

But I can't find a way that can make this work, because it's two thread printing to the same
line

Always, one print would cover the other, and the output become a mess.

I want to know if there's a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `printf` in a mutex so that only one thread can access it at a time.  That will stop your output from being interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution, 
I put every thing in a buffer, and I just print the buffer.